# Laravel 5.8 image failed to upload

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I cannot seem to upload an image file with `Laravel`. I keep getting `the photo failed to upload`.

My form:

```
<form id="save_report_form" action="{{ route('report.add') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" class="upload-photo" id="image" accept="image/png,image/jpg" />
</form>
```

My Controller:

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:png,jpg',
    ]);

    // Get all file details and store in public
    $disk        = Storage::disk('public');
    $file        = $request->file('image');
    $ext         = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename    = $file . '.' . $ext;
    $disk->put($filename, file_get_contents($file), 'public');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I have changed `upload_max_filesize` to `20mb` for my dev server.

Where can I look to find the reason for the upload failure? I am not getting anything in the `Laravel` log. What have I missed. Thanks.

Comment: First of all try `var_dump($file);` and see what it contains.

Comment: your laravel logs are in storage/logs/laravel_todays_date.log

Comment: Laravel docs says Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents, 'public'); you have $disk already looking at public

Comment: is this correct $filename    = $file . '.' . $ext; ?

Answer (score 0):

can you replace

```
 $filename    = $file . '.' . $ext;
```

with

```
$filename = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check what is the result of $filename with dd() /dd($filename) function and see if it is what you expect. If it is not, probably there is the problem.
Also as far as i see in the official docs(https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-visibility) the usage of put() method is exampled without php native file_get_contents(check this also).